# JQuery preventDefault not working with .on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a row of data, which when clicked, show information about the object.

But I also have a button on the row, which when clicked performs some jquery wizzardry.

Anyway, I can't seem to prevent the row click and just fire the button stuffs.

I've tried:

```
return false;
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

This is the function.

```
$('#check_container').on('click', '.show_sub_orgs', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    e.stopPropagation();

    return false;
```

I have all 3 in there at the moment, but that's just for example. Although I have tried all 3 in there, but I have also tried each one separately.

Heres the HTML

```
<div class="row" id="check_container">
    <div id='table_holder' class="col-md-12" >      
        <table id="org_table" class="sortable table table-striped tablesorter">
                <?php
                    if(empty($org_data2)) {
                        // if there is no data for the selected filter
                        echo "There are no organisations set up.";  
                    } else {
                        echo "      
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Sub Orgs</th>
                                    <th>Locations</th>
                                    <th>Users</th>
                                    <th>Compliance</th>
                                    <th>O/D Checks</th>
                                    <th>O/D Training</th>
                                    <th>Renewal</th>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody> 
                        ";
                        foreach ($org_data2 as $orgs) {
                            if(!$orgs->descendant) {
                                echo "<tr id='" . $orgs->org_id . "' class='edit_org_row clickable'>";
                                echo "<td>" . (($orgs->ancestor)?'<div id="' . $orgs->org_id . '" class="show_sub_orgs btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Show Sub-Orgs"><i class="fa fa-expand" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>':'') . "</td>";
                                echo "<td data-title='Name'>" . $orgs->org_name . "</td>";
                                echo "<td data-title='Sub Orgs' class='text-center'></td>";
                                echo "<td data-title='Locations' class='text-center'>" . $orgs->locations . "</td>";
                                echo "<td data-title='Users' class='text-center'>" . $orgs->users . "</td>";
                                echo "<td data-title='Compliance' class='text-center'></td>";
                                echo "<td data-title='O/D Checks' class='text-center'>" . $orgs->checks . "</td>";
                                echo "<td data-title='O/D Training' class='text-center'>" . $orgs->training . "</td>";
                                echo "<td data-title='Renewal'>" . date("d/m/Y", strtotime($orgs->renewal_date)) . "</td>";
                                echo "<td data-title='Actions'><div data-id='3' id='" . $orgs->org_id . "' class='btn admin_login btn-success btn-sm' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Login as customer'>Login</div><div data-id='2' id='" . $orgs->org_id . "' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Disable customer'>Disable</div></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>                
    </div>          
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can we see your html?

Comment: Odd, using `e.stopPropagation()` works perfectly for me with this html http://codepen.io/jb06/pen/eBygJo

Comment: mmmm, something very strange is going on!

Comment: What on earth can be the reason. 3 hours later still cant get this to work.

Comment: Can you post the generated html of a row, and the full click events?

Answer (score 2):

When you delegate to a child element you need to use `e.stopImmediatePropigation()`

Jquery uses it's own event system and this will stop any execution on the elements delegated to from the parent. `e.stopPropigation()` will allow all events delegated from the same parent to fire

```js
$('#check_container').on('click', '.show_sub_orgs', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
})
```

Comment: I was really confident this would work. But it didnt?! I've added html above for extra clarity